# Singleton Service in weblogic for cluster timer

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, weblogic, ejb-3.0, cluster-computing

I am using Weblogic 11. Ejb3.0

I am trying to set up a timer in a cluster environment. I understood from the net that it possible to do via the Singleton service of weblogic.

anyone could show me some concrete implementation how to do it and how to connect the java code to that service so it will trigger the code in the set time?

thanks,

ray.

Answer (score 2):

A [SingletonService](http://middlewaremagic.com/weblogic/?p=830) is a service which would be active only in one node of a cluster. It is not directly related to timers.

If you want to set up an EJB3 Timer in a cluster environment you can check [this blog entry](http://shaoxiongyang.blogspot.com/2010/10/how-to-use-ejb-3-timer-in-weblogic-10.html).